# Producing the Nth value of Fibonacci Sequence in Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

This is the program I'm running to print the nth value of the Fibonacci sequence, but I've come across the problem that when I enter an invalid value I defined, it still runs the loop either way. For example if I enter 0, it will print:

"Not a valid number
The 0 value of the Fibonacci Sequence is 0"

Hopefully someone can point out where I made my error, I've reviewed all of my bracketing and I can't find where the mistake might be

```
//position is user input for nth position, fold2 and fnew will calculate fSequence to find value

int position, fold1, fold2, fNew, loopCount;

//telling user what program will do and stipulations on how to get program to execute correctly
System.out.println("This program will tell you the nth value of the Fibonacci sequence.");
System.out.println("Enter an integer (1 - 46):");
position = keyboard.nextInt();

fold1 = 0;
fold2 = 1; 

//setting upper parameters for limit on given positions
if (position < 1 || position > 46){
    System.out.println("Not a valid number");
} 
else {
    for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < position; loopCount++ ){
        fNew = fold1 + fold2;
        fold1 = fold2;
        fold2 = fNew;                       
    }
}

System.out.println("The " + position + " of the Fibonacci Sequence is " + fold1);
```

Comment: Move the last line up one line, so that it's inside the `else` statement's braces.

Comment: IMHO, you should declare the variables close to where they are first used. Declaring all of them in the beginning is only going to confuse the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your
`System.out.println("The " + position + " of the Fibonacci Sequence is " + fold1);` is outside the `else` scope, hence executed no matter what the condition is.

Your code should read,

```
 if (position < 1 || position > 46){
        System.out.println("Not a valid number");
    } 
    else {
        for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < position; loopCount++ ){
            fNew = fold1 + fold2;
            fold1 = fold2;
            fold2 = fNew;
            System.out.println("The " + position + " of the Fibonacci Sequence is " + fold1);                       
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's something I overlooked, such a simple concept. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your last `System.out.println` is outside your `else`, thus it is always called. You should move it into the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You got this line:

```
 System.out.println("The " + position + " of the Fibonacci Sequence is " + fold1);
```

AFTER the else, so it's even after the if statement, thus it will execute in every case, put it inside the else brackets in the end.